# How do I add an array of RecordSets into Cloud Formation using troposphere?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cli, troposphere

I'm using the python module troposphere to create my cloud formation template. Most of it is complete but I seem to be confused about how to create my DNS entries for the load balancer with the RecordSets method/function.  The output for this section is supposed to look like:

```
"devdevopsdemoELBDNSARecord0": {
    "Type": "AWS::Route53::RecordSetGroup",
    "Properties": {
        "HostedZoneName": "FOO.net.",
        "Comment": "Alias targeted to devdevopsdemoELB ELB.",
        "RecordSets": [
            {
             "Name": "devopsdemo.dev.FOO.net.",
             "Type": "A",
             "AliasTarget": {
             "HostedZoneId": {
                 "Fn::GetAtt": [
                    "devdevopsdemoELB",
                    "CanonicalHostedZoneNameID"
                 ]
             },
             "DNSName": {
                 "Fn::GetAtt": [
                 "devdevopsdemoELB",
                 "CanonicalHostedZoneName"
                 ]
             }
         }
     },
     {
         "Name": "devopsdemo-dev.FOO.net.",
         "Type": "A",
         "AliasTarget": {
            "HostedZoneId": {
            "Fn::GetAtt": [
               "devdevopsdemoELB",
               "CanonicalHostedZoneNameID"
             ]
         },
         "DNSName": {
             "Fn::GetAtt": [
             "devdevopsdemoELB",
             "CanonicalHostedZoneName"
             ]
         }
     }
 }
```

I've started with:

```
hostedzone = "FOO.net"
myRecordSet = RecordSetType("devdevopsdemoELBDNSARecord0")
myRecordSet.HostedZoneName=Join("", hostedzone, "."])
myRecordSet.Comment="Alias targeted to devdevopsdemoELB ELB."
```

But then I'm not clear on how the RecordSets values should be entered.

I supposed I could just use the straight

```
myRecordSet.RecordSets =
```

And just put the json into place, but that seems a bit like a misuse of the purpose of using troposphere in the first place.

Update: Putting in the json results in this error

AttributeError: AWS::Route53::RecordSet object does not support attribute RecordSets

```
myRecordSet.RecordSets = [
                         {
                          "Name": "devopsdemo.dev.FOO.net.",
                          "Type": "A",
                          "AliasTarget": {
                              "HostedZoneId": {
                                  "Fn::GetAtt": [
                                      "devdevopsdemoELB",
                                      "CanonicalHostedZoneNameID"
                                  ]
                              },
                              "DNSName": {
                                  "Fn::GetAtt": [
                                      "devdevopsdemoELB",
                                      "CanonicalHostedZoneName"
                                      ]
                                  }
                              }
                         },
                         {
                          "Name": "devopsdemo-dev.FOO.net.",
                          "Type": "A",
                          "AliasTarget": {
                                 "HostedZoneId": {
                                  "Fn::GetAtt": [
                                      "devdevopsdemoELB",
                                      "CanonicalHostedZoneNameID"
                                      ]
                                  },
                                 "DNSName": {
                                     "Fn::GetAtt": [
                                         "devdevopsdemoELB",
                                         "CanonicalHostedZoneName"
                                         ]
                                     }
                                 }
                          }
                         ]
```

Then I tried this:

```
myDNSRecord = t.add_resource(RecordSetGroup(
        "devdevopsdemoELBDNSARecord0",
        HostedZoneName=Join("", ["inpwrd.net", "."]),
        Comment="DNS Entry to point to the ELB for devopsdemo",
        RecordSets=[
            RecordSet(
                Name="devopsdemo.dev.inpwrd.net.",
                Type="A",
                AliasTarget=[HostedZoneId(GetAtt("devdevopsdemoELB", "CanonicalHostedZoneNameID")),
                             DNSName(GetAtt("devdevopsdemoELB", "CanonicalHostedZoneName"))],
                ),
            RecordSet(
                Name="devopsdemo-dev.inpwrd.net.",
                Type="A",
                AliasTarget=[HostedZoneId(GetAtt("devdevopsdemoELB", "CanonicalHostedZoneNameID")),
                             DNSName(GetAtt("devdevopsdemoELB", "CanonicalHostedZoneName"))],
                ),
            ],
    )
)
```

HostedZoneId isn't found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AliasTarget takes an AliasTarget helper class so you want to do it this way:

```
from troposphere import GetAtt, Join, Template
from troposphere.route53 import AliasTarget, RecordSetType, RecordSetGroup, RecordSet

t = Template()

myDNSRecord = t.add_resource(RecordSetGroup(
        "devdevopsdemoELBDNSARecord0",
        HostedZoneName=Join("", ["example.net", "."]),
        Comment="DNS Entry to point to the ELB for devopsdemo",
        RecordSets=[
            RecordSet(
                Name="devopsdemo.dev.example.net.",
                Type="A",
                AliasTarget=AliasTarget(
                    GetAtt("devdevopsdemoELB", "CanonicalHostedZoneNameID"),
                    GetAtt("devdevopsdemoELB", "CanonicalHostedZoneName"),
                ),
            ),
            RecordSet(
                Name="devopsdemo-dev.example.net.",
                Type="A",
                AliasTarget=AliasTarget(
                    GetAtt("devdevopsdemoELB", "CanonicalHostedZoneNameID"),
                    GetAtt("devdevopsdemoELB", "CanonicalHostedZoneName"),
                ),
            ),
        ],
    )
)

print t.to_json()
```